# Intento enlazar CSS en HTML para ponerlo en web hosting pero no encuentra el link rel

Tags: html, css, flask, deployment

Intento subir a python anywhere una app muy sencilla pero no me deja el HTML enlazar el CSS estático:

```
<"{{ url_FOR('static', filename='index.css') }}">
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] para que sepas como elaborar una buena pregunta y sigue las recomendaciones que te dan al momento de formular la pregunta

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: Hola! gracias por la bienvenida. Me aseguraré de leer los ejemplos para hacer mis preguntas eficientes. Escribí el post por que estaba un poco frustrada por no poder avanzar en eso ya que nunca había desplegado en python anywhere, pero al final si lo logré. ¡Saludos!